# Can we standardize The Sims tags?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-rename-request, tag-synonyms

A the moment we have:

- [sims-2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sims-2)
- [sims-3](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sims-3) (with a tag synonym [the-sims-3](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-sims-3))
- [sims-4](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sims-4)

But the original game is tagged as [the-sims](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-sims), and we also have the series one named [the-sims-series](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-sims-series)

Can we decide whether or not the article is needed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Added "the" to front of all of these tags, and made the original tags all synonyms now.